# How to make android app icon display correctly?

Tags: android

I have tried changing different settings, using different image sizes and using different image shapes but nothing has worked. Do I need to add a version with rounded corners to my android studio file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on drawable folder > new > image asset.

In the asset studio it will automatically generate the app icon shape, you just have to pick your transparent logo on the foreground layer and pick the white color on the background layer. So no need to provide rounded corners version

[image]

[image]